# Able to use Spinnaker without a Cloud provider?

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, spinnaker

My team is working on improving our CI/CD pipeline, and have started looking into Spinnaker. We don't yet have a cloud platform, but would like to try and setup a POC in a local environment. Is this possible? I have seen plenty of articles about setting up the local environment, but it still seems like we have to choose a cloud provider.

Does anyone have experience with this, or is it not possible?

NOTE: In the future we plan to have a cloud provider, but due to time constraints around having infrastructure provisioned it would be in our best interest to start out locally and add the cloud later.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "cloud" provider to run and trial Spinnaker, you can install it on top of VM(s). 
Spinnaker is also a deployment system which can deploy to various [providers](https://www.spinnaker.io/concepts/providers/).
To play around with pipelines you can just replace Deploy stage with Wait stage.
But you will get more insights if run local instance of K8s and configure Spinnaker to deploy in it.
During PoC stage in our company we had small K8s cluster on top of VMs with 2 namespaces - one for Spinnaker and one for applications to be deployed.
Now we have 5 installations of Spinnaker on top of AWS EKS clusters.

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful information. I will be in touch again as i'm sure there will be plenty of configuration items my team will need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible. I run spinnaker Open source from a K3S cluster in a local ubuntu server. There is a project by Armory called Minnaker that automates this. I highly recommend you try it out for PoC and even some Prod deployments. It works fine and it doesnt add all the complexities of installations.

[Minnaker Project on GitHub](https://github.com/armory/minnaker)